# Mostrar dados vindas do BD conforme selecionar uma opção do select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um sistema onde o usuário fará o cadastro das informações conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem que o cadastro inclui fornecedores. Esses dados irão aparecer em um outro formulário conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que o usuário ao selecionar um dos fornecedores, aparecesse apenas as informações referentes a ele vidas do BD. Minha dúvida é no Jquery ou JavaScript e não na programação, já que o cadastro já está sendo efetuado, bastando apenas essa visualização.

Da forma estática tenho esse código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $('#select').on('change',function(){    
    var valor = '#'+$(this).val();    
    $('#pai').children('div').hide();    
    $('#pai').childrenvalor).show();   
  });  
});
```

Mas como eu faria de forma dinâmica?

Comment: mas se a dúvida é no `javascript`, coloque na pergunta o seu código `javascript` para podermos ver, caso contrário a resposta seria "sim, é possível filtrar com javascript"

Comment: Então Ricardo, se eu tivesse o código javascript, não estaria aqui postando minha dúvida.

Comment: então quer um código javascript pronto para fazer o filtro, é isso?

Comment: Ricardo, não tenho muita experiência com jquery ou javascript. O código que tenho e uso é esse: `$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#select').on('change',function(){
   var valor = '#'+$(this).val();
   $('#pai').children('div').hide();
   $('#pai').childrenvalor).show();
  });
});`, porém preciso de forma dinâmica com valores vindos do BD conforme as opções do select.

Comment: acho que entendi, abaixo desse select tem uma lista com vários fornecedores (li, table, etc), e quer esconder e mostrar só o selecionado, é isso?

Comment: Isso. Porém são dados dinâmicos, ou seja, virão as informações do BD relacionadas a cada fornecedor. De forma estática sei fazer, a minha dificuldade está porque é dinâmico.